# Directed to wrong url

Tags: android, url

I can easily navigate the second link but when I try to navigate first link, I'm directed to the wrong url. Here is the code:

```
StringBuilder footerBuffer = new StringBuilder();
footerBuffer.append("<b>Init:</b> http://127.0.0.1:8080/ABC/init/library?bookId=173&auth=1568&delta=yes <br/>");
footerBuffer.append("<b>Home:</b> https://127.0.0.1:8443/ABC <br/>");
footer.setText(Html.fromHtml(footerBuffer.toString()));
```

The url that I'm directed for the first url is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/ABC/init/library?bookId=173&auth=1568%CE%B4=yes
```

I see `%CE%B4` in spite of `&delta`. What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't usually build URLs like this, might just be me but seems a little weird to me ( correct me if i'm wrong! :) ). You should be encoding the url or storing it in it's own string variable.
The URL append structure looks a bit messy, might be invalid.

Comment: No problem when I write first link to web browser. In addition, my second link works perfect. I could not understand why my &delta region is converted to some characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `&delta;` is character reference name for `δ`, see http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/named-character-references.html#entity-delta.

You should escape characters with `Html.escapeHtml()` or whatever. `Html.escapeHtml()` requires API level 16 or above. If you want to work on lower API level, see Apache Commons Lang.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

`&delta;` is a HTML special character (like `&amp;` and so on) - I believe that &delta is converted to the url encoding of the delta character. You could try using %26 (which is the url-encoded value of &) instead of the ampersand for the delta parameter.

Comment: How should I do that? "127.0.0.1:8080/ABC/init/library?bookId=173&auth=1568%26delta=yes" does not work!